# Wordpress5.2.3: Better File Download Plugin validation issue

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, pdf

I am using **Better File Download** plugin for uploading a PDF file from the Admin panel.

The issue is it allows all file type which listed in wp_get_mime_types() function.

I want to give a validation which can allow **ONLY** PDF file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is better suited to the plugin's official support streams.

Comment: Thanks for response..